# Django3x RuntimeError:

Tags: django, model

I am learning Django 3x and when I try to add a path in config/urls.html
"path( cheeses/',
include('everycheese.cheeses.urls', namespace='cheeses'),
),", it throws an  runtimeerror, "RuntimeError: Model class everycheese.cheeses.models.Cheese doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS."

I searched for solutions but found the existing answers cannot fix it.

Could anyone help me?
Thank you.

```
./config/urls.html
...
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        "",
        TemplateView.as_view(template_name="pages/home.html"),
        name="home",
    ),
    path(
        "about/",
        TemplateView.as_view(template_name="pages/about.html"),
        name="about",
    ),
    # Django Admin, use {% url 'admin:index' %}
    path(settings.ADMIN_URL, admin.site.urls),
    # User management
    path(
        "users/",
        include("everycheese.users.urls", namespace="users"),
    ),
    path("accounts/", include("allauth.urls")),
    # Your stuff: custom urls includes go here
    path(
      'cheeses/',
       include('everycheese.cheeses.urls', namespace='cheeses'),
    ),
   
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
...


./cheeses/models.py
from django.db import models

from autoslug import AutoSlugField
from model_utils.models import TimeStampedModel

class Cheese(TimeStampedModel):
    class Firmness(models.TextChoices):
        UNSPECIFIED = "unspecified", "Unspecified"
        SOFT = "soft", "Soft"
        SEMI_SOFT = "semi-soft", "Semi-Soft"
        SEMI_HARD = "semi-hard", "Semi-Hard"
        HARD = "hard", "Hard"

    name = models.CharField("Name of Cheese", max_length=255)
    slug = AutoSlugField("Cheese Address",
        unique=True, always_update=False, populate_from="name")

    description = models.TextField("Description", blank=True)

    firmness = models.CharField("Firmness", max_length=20,
        choices=Firmness.choices, default=Firmness.UNSPECIFIED)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the path wrong, it is suppposed to be used to redirect to a url.py page on your app.

Instead of what you are doing their should be one path saying:

path('', include('NAMEOFAPP.urls')),

Comment: Do you meam in ./config/urls.html I should add 
"path(
       "users/",
       include("everycheese.users.urls),
    ), "  instead of 

"path(
      "users/",
      include("everycheese.users.urls", namespace="users"),
    )," ?

Comment: Can you just specify for me if this is the main urls.py sections

Comment: I think I'm wrong because it dosen't work .Please more details on it

Comment: Yes,  ./config/urls.py is the main urls.py  I have ./cheeses/urls.py and  ./user/urls.py

Comment: That is good, but you should not need to do  everycheese.user.urls, it should just be user.urls

Comment: C:\Users\hxd66\projects\everycheese\config\urls.py
C:\Users\hxd66\projects\everycheese\everycheese\users\urls.py
C:\Users\hxd66\projects\everycheese\everycheese\cheeses\urls.py
C:\Users\hxd66\projects\everycheese\everycheese\cheeses\models.py

Comment: But ,I do have a everycheese.users.url.py file in the project.

Comment: The only error i can think of now is a syntax error, maybe you wrote cheese instead of cheeses somewhere.